# In comparing survival estimates, why are there overlapped confidence intervals but still significant difference?

Tags: survival

Below is the graph of Kaplan-Meier estimates comparing between males and females [image]

So it looks like there is substantial overlapping between two confidence intervals (Hall-Wellner confidence bands)
And the tests of equality are significant:

Test of Equality over Strata
Test    Chi-Square  DF  Pr >
Chi-Square
Log-Rank    7.7911  1   0.0053
Wilcoxon    5.5370  1   0.0186
-2Log(LR)   10.5120     1   0.0012

So is it that these two are not related with each other, i.e., there can be overlapped confidence intervals but still significant difference? As well, whatever the answer, is it applicable universally or only for survival analysis?

Source: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_survival/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variances add together, not the standard deviations.  As a result, the standard deviation of the difference between the two can be greater or smaller than the sum of the two sd's individually.

sd1+sd2 > sqrt(sd1^2+sd2^2) in this case, because the difference is significant. The chi squared test that you're concerned about is also based off of the square of a normal distribution, so the distances are similarly warped.